# SQL logic to determine unsold inventory and corresponding available dates (Available to sell)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for advice on how to generate SQL to be used in SQL Server that will show available inventory to sell and the corresponding date that said inventory will be available. I am easily able to determine if we have inventory that is available immediately but can't wrap my head around what logic would be needed to determine future available quantities.

In the below table. The +/- column represents the weekly inbound vs outbound and the quantity available is a rolling SUM OVER PARTITION BY of the +/- column. I was able to get the immediate quantity available through this simple logic:

```
Case when Min(X.Qty_Available) > 0 Then Min(X.Qty_Available) else 0 END 
AS Immediate_available_Qty
```

Table:

```
+-------------+---------------+---------------+------+---------------+
| Item Number |   Item Name   | week_end_date |  +/- | Qty_Available |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+------+---------------+
|      123456 | Fidget Widget | 7/13/2019     |  117 |           117 |
|      123456 | Fidget Widget | 7/20/2019     |   49 |           166 |
|      123456 | Fidget Widget | 7/27/2019     |   -7 |           159 |
|      123456 | Fidget Widget | 8/3/2019      |  -12 |           147 |
|      123456 | Fidget Widget | 8/10/2019     |   -1 |           146 |
|      123456 | Fidget Widget | 8/17/2019     |   45 |           191 |
|      123456 | Fidget Widget | 8/24/2019     |   -1 |           190 |
|      123456 | Fidget Widget | 8/31/2019     |   -1 |           189 |
|      123456 | Fidget Widget | 9/7/2019      |   50 |           239 |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+------+---------------+
```

My desired results of this query would be as follows:

```
+-----------+-----+
|  Output   | Qty |
+-----------+-----+
| 7/13/2019 | 117 |
| 7/20/2019 |  29 |
| 8/17/2019 |  43 |
+-----------+-----+
```

the second availability is determined by taking the first available quantity of 117 out of each line in Qty_Available column and finding the new minimum. If the new min is Zero, find the next continuously positive string of data (that runs all the way to the end of the data). Repeat for the third_available quantity and then stop.

I was on the thought train of pursuing RCTE logic but don't want to dive into that rabbit hole if there is a better way to tackle this issue and I'm not even sure the RCTE work for this problem?

Comment: I can't say I understand how `117 + 49 = 29`. Can you explain? HOw is that `29` even worked out, I can't see how you can take the numbers `117` and `49` and get `29` in any way.

Comment: I understand how you get to your expected resuts (take the a positive value and reduce it by all the negative values till the next positive value is reached)... but still this doesn't make any sense at all to me. What is the business idea behind this? In your example, 117 is the start value. The next value is 49 - which seems to be additional articles... so the 166 in your first example seem OK. Now you start to reduce the value by 7, 12 and 1... BUT at the time you have the 117 (or 49) you do NOT know if in the next days the stock will be reduced. So, what are you trying to calculate?

Comment: Thanks all, the business practice behind this is the supply chain concept of "Available to Sell". I want to know when I will have positive inventory values, report those and account for values that I have reported for previously. The 117 is the minimum overall value. If you subtract that from every value in Qty_Available that's dated past 7/13  and find the new minimum value, it's 29 on 8/10 but that inventory is available as soon as 7/20. Now subtract the 117+29 from all future values past 8/10, the new minimum is 43 available as soon as 8/17. Basically, this is a report showing unsold inboun

Comment: Did you try my answer, it returns your expected answer? If it's not what you want you better create a fiddle with more data and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what I came up with. I know this is poor, I didn't want to leave this thread high and dry and maybe I can get more insight on a better path. Please know that I've never had any real training so I don't know what I don't know.

I ended up running this into a temp table and altering the commented out section in table "A". then re-running that into a temp table.

```
Select 
F.Upc,
F.name,
F.Week_end_date as First_Available_Date,
E.Qty_Available_1

From
    (
    Select Distinct 
    D.Upc,
    D.name,
    Case When Min(D.Rolling_Qty_Available) Over ( PARTITION BY D.upc) < 1 then 0 else 
    Min(D.Rolling_Qty_Available) Over ( PARTITION BY D.upc) END as Qty_Available_1,
    Case When Max(D.Look_up_Ref) Over ( PARTITION BY D.upc) = 0 then '-1000' else 
    Max(D.Look_up_Ref) Over ( PARTITION BY D.upc) END as Look_up_Ref_1

From
    (
    Select 
    A.Upc,
    A.name,
    A.Week_end_Date,
    A.Rolling_Qty_Available,
    CASE WHEN 
    C.Max_Row = A.Row_num and A.[Rolling_Qty_Available] >1 THEN 1 
    ELSE
    CASE WHEN
    Sum(A.Calc_Row_Thing) OVER (Partition by A.UPC Order by A.Row_Num DESC
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
    AND   Current ROW
    ) = (C.Max_Row - A.Row_num + 1)
    THEN
    C.Max_Row - A.Row_num + 1
    ELSE 0 END 
    END as Look_up_Ref

    FROM    (
                        Select
                        G.Upc,
                        G.Name,
                        G.Week_End_Date,
                        G.Row_num,
                        G.Calc_Row_Thing,
                        G.Rolling_Qty_Available 
                        --CASE When (G.Rolling_Qty_Available - 
                        --isnull(H.Qty_Available_1,0)) > 0 then 1 else - 0 END as 
                        --Calc_Row_Thing,


                        From [dbo].[ATS_item_detail_USA_vw] as G
                        --Left Join [dbo].[tmp_ats_usa_qty_1] as H on G.upc = H.upc

            ) AS A --Need to subtract QTY 1 out of here and below

join ( 

        SELECT 
        B.upc,
        Max(Row_num) AS Max_Row

        FROM [dbo].[ATS_item_detail_USA_vw] AS B

        GROUP BY B.upc

        ) as C on A.upc = C.upc

    ) as D

GROUP BY 
D.Upc,
D.name,
D.Rolling_Qty_Available,
D.Look_up_Ref
HAVING Max(D.Look_up_Ref) > 1
) as E 

Left join 
        (
        SELECT 
        A.Upc,
        A.name,
        A.Week_end_Date,
        A.Rolling_Qty_Available,
        CASE WHEN 
        C.Max_Row = A.Row_num and A.[Rolling_Qty_Available] >1 THEN 1 
        ELSE
        CASE WHEN
        Sum(A.Calc_Row_Thing) OVER (Partition by A.UPC Order by A.Row_Num DESC
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
        AND   Current ROW
        ) = (C.Max_Row - A.Row_num + 1)
        THEN
        C.Max_Row - A.Row_num + 1
        ELSE 0 END 
        END as Look_up_Ref

        From (

                            Select
                        G.Upc,
                        G.Name,
                        G.Week_End_Date,
                        G.Row_num,
                        G.Calc_Row_Thing,
                        G.Rolling_Qty_Available 
                        --CASE When (G.Rolling_Qty_Available - 
                        --isnull(H.Qty_Available_1,0)) > 0 then 1 else - 0 END as 
                        --Calc_Row_Thing,


                        From [dbo].[ATS_item_detail_USA_vw] as G
                        --Left Join [dbo].[tmp_ats_usa_qty_1] as H on G.upc = H.upc

            ) as A --subtract qty_1 out the start qty 2 calc

        join ( 
                    SELECT 
                    B.upc,
                    Max(Row_num) as Max_Row

                    FROM [dbo].[ATS_item_detail_USA_vw] as B

                        GROUP BY B.upc
                ) AS C ON A.upc = C.upc

            ) AS F ON E.upc = F.upc and E.Look_up_Ref_1 = F.Look_up_Ref
```

Answer (score 0):

This should return your expected result:

```
SELECT Item_Number, Min(week_end_date), Sum("+/-")
FROM
 (
   SELECT *
      -- put a positive value plus all following negative values in the same group
      -- using a Cumulative Sum over 0/1
     ,Sum(CASE WHEN "+/-" > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) 
      Over (PARTITION BY Item_Number
            ORDER BY week_end_date
            ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS grp
   FROM my_table
 ) AS dt
WHERE grp <= 3 -- only the 1st 3 groups
GROUP BY Item_Number, grp
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I tried this out but did not achieve the desired result. The above only shows if the weekly level inbound vs outbound is positive and returns that weekending date. I'm trying to get a lot more detail than that where I need previous results to deduct from the data set and recalc mins from that set. I have a really really bad solution that I may be embarrassed to share in the works right now, I will post up once complete.

Comment: Well, currently only you know what you want, (at least) to me all your explanations were not understandable. Setup a fiddle, add some more data and detailed calculations how you get your result.